# Does Amazon Aurora support serializable isolation?

Tags: database, amazon-aurora

In other words, is phantom write possible on Amazon Aurora?

I cannot find any document on Amazon that discusses the limitation. 
From their Aurora paper, it only explains how to achieve consensus across replicas, which I understand. However, it does not explain how transaction isolation is achieved.

Comment: I think that aurora should give the same guarantees as either mysql or postgres (depending on which engine you're running). I think they basically forked both and added some special sauce to make aurora.

Comment: I'm not sure. MySQL and postgres are designed to run on a single host. Aurora replaces their backend storage with a disaggregated distributed storage. I'm wondering the technical reason why the strict serializability can still hold, if it does.